# Pattern for parallel task execution

Tags: java

I have 2 tasks to run in parallel. Another, 3rd task, has to be launched after the other 2 have been completed. To kick off the 3rd task I use a counter variable = 2, which I decrement when each of the first 2 tasks complete. After each decrement there is a check whether counter == 0 and if it  does - the 3rd task starts.

The check is carried out on UI thread in a callback like this:

```
   @Override
   protected void onSuccess(Object data) {
      // decrement the counter

      // decide whether to kick off the 3rd task
   }
```

I can't use `join` here - even if I could - it would stall the UI thread. So I use this counter.

I just wanted to ask whether there's a native component/pattern for that technique in java.

Thanks.

Comment: Using `CountDownLatch` is better alternative as @Ankur suggested, but if you have struck with current approach make sure that your counter synchronized or use `AtomicInteger` for thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) api to achieve this effectively in Java.
You can go through this [sample article on CountDownLatch](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/07/countdownlatch-example-in-java.html) to get a gist of its usage.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for doing this that are idiomatic in Java:

1) A [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html): This is essentially your *counter*. Make the third thread wait on it, the CountDownLatch will only let this thread continue when the counter reaches 0.

2) Using [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html): Use an executor to launch each task in parallel and return (immediately) a FutureTask, then pass the FutureTasks to you your third task and make that task call the *get* method in the Futures. This will block your third task until the first 2 are completed or throw an exception.

The second way doesn't require you to handle threads explicitly and allow you to process failures.

Answer (score 0):

You have following options:

1) start each task on a separate thread, and let 3d task first execute

```
 join(thread1);
 join(thread1);
```

this is simplest way but the 3d thread wastes resources (memory) while waiting. As others suggested, `CountDownLatch.await()` or `FutureTask.get()` can be used instead of `join()s`, but it does not make much difference.

2) represent each task as a Runnable to be submitted to a thread pool, and create a coordinating object with a method like `onSuccess` you described in the question. "kick off" there should mean `threadpool.execute(task3)`. This object can also keep results of the first 2 tasks and pass them to the 3d task before submitting. Unfortunately, j.u.c. has no ready component for such a task coordination, but it can easily be implemented from scratch.

3)  start each task on a separate thread, and create a coordinating object with a method `onSuccess`, but "kick off" there should mean direct invocation of a method which executes task3. This way you need not separate thread pool (or, you have a specialized thread pool of 2 threads).

In any variant, you need not to use GUI thread to run `onSuccess` method, just invoke it directly.